# Count Value of multi dimensional array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
var sortedArr = [["Paul",     "1355"],
  ["Jennifer", "1910"],
  ["John",      "835"],
  ["John",      "830"],
  ["Paul",     "1315"],
  ["John",     "1615"],
  ["John",     "1640"],
  ["Paul",     "1405"],
  ["John",      "855"],
  ["John",      "930"],
  ["John",      "915"],
  ["John",      "730"],
  ["John",      "940"],
  ["Jennifer", "1335"],
  ["Jennifer",  "730"],
  ["John",     "1630"],
  ["Jennifer",    "5"]
];
```

I am trying to find the total number of counts for each key, For example, Paul appears three times so Paul should count 3 times.

and then want to write all the values for it. For example for Paul value should be 1355 1315 1405

It should be Like Paul 1355, 1315, 1405

I try something, but I get some issues, the issue are more about logic. Can someone please guide me?

```
  count = 1;
 var test;

//sortedArr = arr.sort();

for (var i = 0; i < sortedArr.length; i = i + count) {

  count = 1;
  test = [];
  test.push(sortedArr[i][1]);
 
  for (var j = i + 1; j < sortedArr.length; j++) {
  
    if (sortedArr[i][0] === sortedArr[j][0])
    {
      count++;
     // 
       test.push(sortedArr[j][1]);
       
  }
  }
  document.write(sortedArr[i][0]  +test +" = " + count + "<br>");
 
}
```

Output (wrong)

```
Paul1355,1315,1405 = 3
John830,1615,1640,855,930,915,730,940,1630 = 9
John940,1630 = 2
Jennifer730,5 = 2
Jennifer5 = 1
```

Output should be

```
Paul1355,1315,1405 = 3
John835, 830,1615,1640,855,930,915,730,940,1630 = 10
Jennifer1910, 1335, 730,5 = 4
```

Can someone tell me the issue in my code?

Answer (score 2):

Your `sortedArr` isn't sorted, so the results are erratic. In JavaScript, `sort()` modifies the array directly, so you only need to add

```
sortedArr.sort();
```

and your code works.

```js
var sortedArr = [["Paul",     "1355"],
  ["Jennifer", "1910"],
  ["John",      "835"],
  ["John",      "830"],
  ["Paul",     "1315"],
  ["John",     "1615"],
  ["John",     "1640"],
  ["Paul",     "1405"],
  ["John",      "855"],
  ["John",      "930"],
  ["John",      "915"],
  ["John",      "730"],
  ["John",      "940"],
  ["Jennifer", "1335"],
  ["Jennifer",  "730"],
  ["John",     "1630"],
  ["Jennifer",    "5"]
];

 count = 1;
 var test;

sortedArr.sort();

for (var i = 0; i < sortedArr.length; i = i + count) {
  count = 1;
  test = [];
  test.push(sortedArr[i][1]);
 
  for (var j = i + 1; j < sortedArr.length; j++) {    
    if (sortedArr[i][0] === sortedArr[j][0]) {
      count++; 
      test.push(sortedArr[j][1]);     
      }
  }
  document.write(sortedArr[i][0]  +test +" = " + count + "<br>");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first organize the data and then print it to the document.

1. First you can iterate over the array using [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and convert it into object where each field will be `<perosn_name> : <array_of_values>`.
2. Then again iterate to print in the form of `<name> = <comma separated values> = <count>` of the values (using [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach))

Try like below

```js
var sortedArr = [
  ["Paul", "1355"],
  ["Jennifer", "1910"],
  ["John", "835"],
  ["John", "830"],
  ["Paul", "1315"],
  ["John", "1615"],
  ["John", "1640"],
  ["Paul", "1405"],
  ["John", "855"],
  ["John", "930"],
  ["John", "915"],
  ["John", "730"],
  ["John", "940"],
  ["Jennifer", "1335"],
  ["Jennifer", "730"],
  ["John", "1630"],
  ["Jennifer", "5"],
];

// convert the data into the form described
const output = sortedArr.reduce((prevValue, [name, value]) => {
  prevValue[name] ? prevValue[name].push(value) : (prevValue[name] = [value]);
  return prevValue;
}, {});

// write to the document
Object.entries(output).forEach(([name, arr]) => {
  document.write(`${name} = ${arr.join(",")} = ${arr.length}<br>`);
})
```

NOTE: Always try to use the built-in Array prototype functions. Most of the time you can use them and easy to read your code.

Comment: Care to explain what the code is doing and why the OP should use it?

Comment: @Cjmarkham, updated the answer with info

Answer (score 1):

Respecting and understanding the way you are trying to solve the problem, your logic is correct except that it needs a sorted list because your implementation skips consecutive entries with similar names with `count` it has to be sorted for that. So sorting the array before you check the values will give you the proper results:

```
sortedArr.sort((a, b) => b.toString().localeCompare(a.toString()));
```

Note I have sorted the array in descending order to match your output. If you just call `sortedArr.sort()` it should also give the correct results but in reverse output order.

Answer (score -1):

Put all of them in a object, and you can get what you want.

```js
const result = sortedArr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const [name, number] = curr
  if (acc[name]) {
    acc[name].push(number)
  } else {
    acc[name] = [number]
  }
  return acc
},{})

// you can use result["Paul"] to get the count of Paul
// don't need to add count variable
```

Comment: although your solution might work (or is more efficient/clean). the OP has provided a snippet and explicitly asked for "_Can someone tell me the issue in my code?_". It would be more suitable to address that before providing a better alternative/suggestion.

Comment: I think that if you do not rewrite the whole thing, you cannot simply fix the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Map for this use-case

```
let map = new Map();

sortedArr.forEach((item)=>{
  let [key, value] = item;
  if(!map.has(key)) {
    map.set(key, [])
  }
  map.get(key).push(value)
})


for(let [key, value] of map.entries()) {
  console.log(`${key} ${value} = ${value.length}`);
}
```

Output is

```
Paul 1355,1315,1405 = 3
Jennifer 1910,1335,730,5 = 4
John 835,830,1615,1640,855,930,915,730,940,1630 = 10
```